# enabling jmx remote in jboss 6.1

Tags: jboss, jmx

I'm trying to enable jmx remote in jboss 6.1. When I've added  options like below

```
-Djboss.platform.mbeanserver 
-Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=12349
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

, jboss can't start properly and I'got  following error:

```
" Deployment "JBossLogService" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The LogManager was not properly installed (you must set the "java.util.logging.manager" system property to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"), **ERROR**"
```

Do you have any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: Problem disappeared after adding : export JBOSS_CLASSPATH="${JBOSS_CLASSPATH}:/jboss-dir/lib/jboss-logmanager.jar"

Answer (score 5):

In Jboss EAP 6.1 JMX is enabled by default.

ensure you have:

- `<extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>` under `<extensions>`
- ```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.2">
       <expose-resolved-model/>
       <expose-expression-model/>
       <remoting-connector/>  
  </subsystem>
  ```
- use `-Djboss.bind.address.management=YOURSERVERIP` as command line argument to start you AS or change it here:

  ```
  <interfaces>
       <interface name="management">
           <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:**127.0.0.1**}"/>
       </interface>
       ..
   </interfaces>
  ```
- use jconsole start script under JBOSS_HOME/bin/jconsole.sh (it loads JBoss remoting libraries on classpath )
- to use jvisualvm instead refer to https://github.com/johnaoahra80/jboss-as-tool-integration/tree/master/visualvm
- use that url in jconsole `service:jmx:remoting-jmx://yourIP:magementport` (default is 9999)
- use user/password you crated using JBOSS_HOME/bin/add-user.sh

Answer (score 0):

add next options

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
-Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/logmanager/main/jboss-logmanager-version.jar
-Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/log4j/logmanager/main/log4j-jboss-logmanager-version.jar
-Xbootclasspath/p:$JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/org/apache/log4j/main/log4j-jboss-logmanager-version.jar
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
```