# not able to profile remote Jboss through Visualvm

Tags: visualvm

I am new to the profiling of java application. 
I tried to profile my remote application with VisualVM but with no effect. 
I followed the below steps. 
There are three instances in the JBOSS.

The run.conf is as below :

```
PIDDIR=/varsoft/sgdrc/logs/E06/sgdrcCLAS
JBOSS_NAME=sgdrcCLAS
JBOSS_JVMROUTE=iu0376cli:14094
JAVA_OPTS="-XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseParallelGC  -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djboss.server.home.dir=/product/jboss5/jboss-eap-5.0.0.GA/jboss-as/server/sgdrcCLAS/ -Djboss.server.home.url=file:/product/jboss5/jboss-eap-5.0.0.GA/jboss-as/server/sgdrcCLAS/ -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8080 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=14094 -Djboss.jvmroute=${JBOSS_JVMROUTE} -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Djboss.server.log.dir=${PIDDIR} -Xloggc:${PIDDIR}/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Djboss.jvmroute=${JBOSS_JVMROUTE} -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -Djboss.server.log.dir=${PIDDIR} -Xloggc:${PIDDIR}/gc.log"
JBOSS_CLASSPATH=/product/sgdrc/sgdrc/config
```

Followed the below steps

a-> started jstatd with the below command

```
jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=/product/jboss5/jboss-eap-5.0.0.GA/jboss-as/visualvm.policy
```

b-> started the JBOSS instance with the below command in the run.conf

```
JAVA_OPTS="-XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:+UseParallelGC  -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djboss.server.home.dir=/product/jboss5/jboss-eap-5.0.0.GA/jboss-as/server/sgdrcCLAS/ -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8080 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djboss.server.home.url=file:/product/jboss5/jboss-eap-5.0.0.GA/jboss-as/server/sgdrcCLAS/ -Djboss.jvmroute=${JBOSS_JVMROUTE} -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Djboss.server.log.dir=${PIDDIR} -Xloggc:${PIDDIR}/gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -Djboss.jvmroute=${JBOSS_JVMROUTE} -Xms1024m -Xmx2048m -Djboss.server.log.dir=${PIDDIR} -Xloggc:${PIDDIR}/gc.log"
```

c-> tried to connect to visual vm from my local system with the below details:

```
server name:iu0376cli.sfr.com
jmx credentials: iu0376cli.sfr.com:8080
```

I am getting error `'cannot connect to iu0376cli:14094'`.

Can you guys tell me why am not able to connect to the remote and start profiling?

Comment: Guys any help on this ..... am stuck really bad with this

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable remote JMX in JBoss. See the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105933/enabling-jmx-remote-in-jboss-6-1) for info, how to do it. Once this is setup correctly, you can test direct [JMX connection](http://visualvm.java.net/jmx_connections.html) from VisualVM without jstatd. You can add `jstatd` later.